# Is there a way to have both thead fixed at the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, css-position

I need to have both thead to be fixed at the top of the page. For now, only the first thead works as I want.

I have tried `position: sticky`, `class="position-sticky"`, `class="position-absolute`, etc" and all the solutions proposed by boostrap with `class`, but the main issue for me is that the two theads belong to two different tables, one for the header and one for the main section.
If use `class: fixed-top` it works (even though only for the first thead), but then it also covers part of the table, which is something that shouldn't happen.

Here is my JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/m_tibo/yf8a0txL/15/

What I would like to achieve is to be able and scroll down while keeping both theads fixed at the top. For now, I can only achieve the first one.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can see that the 'Lorem Ipsum' and 'About/Contact' are stuck on the top do you also want the 'role', 'project' etc to be stuck on the top?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't fully understand your explanation for the behavior you're looking to achieve. What's the overall end-goal here? I get that you want each thead to be fixed at top, but to what end? What exactly do you want the end user to see?

Comment: @Yash009 actually I want 'role', 'project', etc to be fixed in their actual position, just moving down with 'lorem ipsum', 'about/contact'.

Comment: @silencedogood you're right, it's not completely clear, but unfortuntaley I haven't found any example to show. Actually I'd like for both thead to stay in their position and just scroll down with page when I scroll. I want the user to be able and see the 'about/contact' even when he scrolled at the bottom of the page and have the thead of the table always visible so to have a good understanding of the table at every moment.

Comment: Do you want the two tables to show separately, one on top of the other, with the ability to scroll through each table separately while keeping the header of the table fixed?

Comment: @silencedogood yes, something like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your CSS with this. What you essentially are looking for is position:fixed. Put it in the parent and the header will stick.
You may have to tweak some padding and margin to get the desired result but this should take care of the sticky problem.

Replace chunks of your code with this 
HTML:

```
  <section class="main">
    <table id="maintable">
      <thead class="maintable-header">
        <tr class="second-header">
          <th class="blankHeader"scope="col"></th>
          <th class="tableHeader" scope="col">Role</th>
          <th class="tableHeader" scope="col">Project</th>
          <th class="tableHeader" scope="col">Credits</th>
          <th class="tableHeader" scope="col">Year</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
```

And add these CSS classes:

```
 .second-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 9%;
  background:#fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.tableHeader {
  width: 25%;
}
```

[This is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yash009/yw4fpLr2/14/)

Comment: Thanks very much!